# Перекрытие блока прозрачным блоком

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать так, чтобы один прозрачный блок перекрывал другой?

[image: прозрачный блок]
[image: гифка]

Важно, чтобы структура была примерно такая, т.к. 1-у блоку будет задана анимация, которая будет поднимать его вверх и по мере продвижения будет появляться  2-й блок:

```
<div class="div1"></div> 
<div class="div2"> </div>
```

Comment: Исходя из логических рассуждений, прозрачный блок не сможет перекрыть блок, под прозрачным блоком будет виден перекрываемый блок в зависимости от степени прозрачности. То есть тут может быть только одно: либо перекрывает, либо прозрачный.

Answer (score 1):

Например так:
HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="div1">
<div class="div2"></div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {position:relative;}
.div1 {opacity:0.5; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; z-index:2;}
.div2 {width:500px; height:100px; position:relative; z-index:1;}
```

То есть для прозрачного блока делаем абсолютное позиционирование относительно родителя.

**UPDATE 1**

Ну Вам тогда не подойдет перекрытие. Там нужно делать анимацию меняя padding-top. Тогда будет нужный Вам эффект. Наведите на черный элемент.
Вот [пример на JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmjnoxuc/)

Comment: Спасибо. но не совсем то. добавил гифку в вопрос, чтобы понятнее было

Comment: Ну Вам тогда не подойдет перекрытие. Там нужно делать анимацию меняя padding-top. Тогда будет нужный Вам эффект.

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, чего вы хотите, но это похож на вашу картинку:

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}
#div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">div 1</div>
<div id="div2">div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Прозрачный* ничего перекрывать не может.

Способ 1: вместо прозрачности унаследовать фон.

Способ 2: Второй положить во вреппер с `overflow:hidden` и двигать внутри него.

Способ 3: Использовать clip.